# local stellar mapping data

Tags: star

I've been playing around with Near Star Map, and I think I kind of want something more sophisticated, so for all stars within 100ly/30pc, is the following known?

- velocity (it would be nice to have a vector field showing how fast in which direction stars are moving)
- magnetic field intensity
- estimated age
- local ecliptic plane (and as much as that's meaningful for three-star systems with Poincare-befuddling orbital dynamics)

Comment: Finding the local ecliptic plane would require knowing the star's planets (ie, what we call exoplanets) and their orbits, and deciding which planet(s) get to determine the "ecliptic".

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

We don't even think the census of stars within 30pc is complete, let along have all the other information you want.

For all bright stars (say V<10) and close, there are decent parallaxes and proper motions in the Hipparcos and Tycho catalogues, so you can compile tangential velocities for these. A lot of these will also have radial velocities, but there is no recent uniform catalogue of these. Things like the General catalogues of radial velocities are getting a bit old. The Hipparcos input catalogue might be a reasonable source.

Magnetic fields have been measured on relatively few stars and usually those which are much younger and more active than the Sun.

There is no way of directly measuring stellar ages. This is one of the big problems in astronomy. Estimates can be made for stars in the field but they are rarely more precise than 20-30% and their accuracy, especially for older stars is open to question. I know of no uniform compilation that would help.

If you were to restrict your sample to even closer to the Earth, then you might find that the [RECONS](http://www.recons.org/) database for stars closer than 10pc might be of use.